# How do I get the background of flash player to be transparent

Tags: dreamweaver, flash

I dont know much about how the flash object works , but I am embedding a video in Dreamweaver ,and there is a white background on the background.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="360" height="240" id="FLVPlayer">
  <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
  <param name="salign" value="lt" />
```

Comment: Change the value in the code you show

Comment: you're welcome. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `wmode` property to `transparent`.

However, be sure to test it. From [Adobe Support:](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html)

> Not every web browser handles transparency in the same way. Be sure to test your SWF file in all browsers that you want to enable your audience to use. Most Linux browsers do not support Flash transparency. This table lists several browsers that support transparency.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to set a property  to align to the left?

Comment: @Tony you mean in Flash? I don't think that can be done from outside Flash

Comment: yes because what is happening, is the video still gets the margins from the white box  and I need to float left

Comment: @Tony if the margin is inside the Flash movie, I don't think there is anything you can do (except try and adjust the size, if it's a size issue)

Comment: Lastly how do I make a full screen mode?